# Shows warning when enable "wp_gallery_custom_links" plugin with Themify Builder

Tags: plugins, functions, themes

When I have installed this plugin with one of my site which use Themify Builder, it shows below error.

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function ‘wp_gallery_custom_links’ not found or invalid function name in /home/content/xxxxx/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 298
```

Did you or anyone face this error before? Is there any quick solution?

Also, I have checked Themify and found that they have added plugin code in compatible file as below.

```
    // WP Gallery Custom Links
if( $this->is_plugin_active( 'wp-gallery-custom-links/wp-gallery-custom-links.php' ) ) {
add_filter( 'themify_builder_image_link_before', 'wp_gallery_custom_links', 10, 3 );
}

function wp_gallery_custom_links( $link_before, $image, $settings ) {
        $attachment_meta = get_post_meta( $image->ID, '_gallery_link_url', true );
        if( $attachment_meta ) {
            $link_before = preg_replace( '/href="(.*)"/', 'href="' . $attachment_meta . '"', $link_before );
        }
        $attachment_meta = get_post_meta( $image->ID, '_gallery_link_target', true );
        if( $attachment_meta ) {
            $link_before = str_replace( '>', ' target="' . $attachment_meta . '">', $link_before );
        }

        return $link_before;
    }
```

Please look into this and let me know solution asap.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue finally by making changes directly in “/wp-content/themes/themify-ultra/themify/themify-builder/templates/template-gallery-grid.php”.

Try to find below lines.

```
$link_before = '' != $link ? sprintf( '', esc_attr( $image->post_title ), esc_url( $link ) ) : '';
$link_before = apply_filters( 'themify_builder_image_link_before', $link_before, $image, $settings );
```

And replace with,

```
$custom_link = get_post_meta( $image->ID, '_gallery_link_url', true );
$custom_link_target = get_post_meta( $image->ID, '_gallery_link_target', true );
if($custom_link){
   $link = $custom_link;
}
$link_before = '' != $link ? sprintf( '', esc_attr( $image->post_title ), esc_url( $link ), $custom_link_target ) : '';
//$link_before = apply_filters( 'themify_builder_image_link_before', $link_before, $image, $settings );
```

Thanks